# Replace values from one list of columns from another list of columns based on conditions in R or python

Tags: python, r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

(for pythonistas, the below code is in R's format before I get some #hatehard)

This one has been frustrating me for a way too long.

I have 2 datasets

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("Person.A", "Person.B", "Person.C", "Person.D", "Person.E", "Person.F"),
                  Aa = c(0,1,2,NA,1,1),
                  Ab = c(0,NA,2,1,1,1),
                  Ac = c(NA,NA,2,2,1,1),
                  no.match = c(0,1,2,2,1,2))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("Person.A", "Person.B", "Person.C", "Person.D", "Person.E"),
                  Ba = c(0,NA,2,1,1),
                  Bb = c(NA,1,2,2,1),
                  Bc = c(0,1,2,2,1))
```

I then merge these 2 datasets using `merge(df1, df2, all.x = T, by = "ID"` to get:

```
         ID Aa Ab Ac no.match Ba Bb Bc
1 Person.A  0  0 NA        0  0 NA  0
2 Person.B  1 NA NA        1 NA  1  1
3 Person.C  2  2  2        2  2  2  2
4 Person.D NA  1  2        2  1  2  2
5 Person.E  1  1  1        1  1  1  1
6 Person.F  1  1  1        2 NA NA NA
```

The actual datasets are much more complicated with lots of columns that have no matches in other columns. So I don't think I could do something that depends on the arrangement of the columns.

Columns `Aa` and `Ba` contain the same information; and columns `Ab` and `Bb` do as well, and so on, but column `no.match` does not contain a matching column.

I want to "map" the values from from the same row of `Ba` to `Aa` *if* `Aa` is NA and do the same for `Ab` and `Bb`, `Ac` and `Bc`, etc.

The result DF in this case would look like:

```
        ID Aa Ab Ac no.match Ba Bb Bc
1 Person.A  0  0  0      0    0 NA  0
2 Person.B  1  1  1      1    NA  1  1
3 Person.C  2  2  2      2    2  2  2
4 Person.D  1  1  2      2    1  2 NA
5 Person.E  1  1  1      1    1  1  1
6 Person.F  1  1  1      2    NA NA NA
```

Where element `[4,2]` was replaced by element `[4,6]`
The rows and the columns need to match up.

I've tried an embarrassingly large number of things: `apply`, `ifelse`, iterating through a list of columns `l1 = c('Aa','Ab','Ac'), l2 = c('Ba', 'Bb', 'Bc')`

I can do the one-off: `which(is.na(mdf$Aa)) <- mdf[which(is.na(mdf$Aa)), c("Ba")]`

But how can I do this iteratively?

Thank you! (sorry for the long-windedness)

Comment: I think I might have just been being so freaking dense. I don't know if this makes me happy or sad, but I think I got something to work. I'd still be interested in a more elegant solution if anyone has one.  Thanks again! I think just writing the problem out, helped me. `mdf[, c("Aa", "Ab", "Ac")][is.na(mdf[, c("Aa", "Ab", "Ac")])] <- mdf[, c("Ba", "Bb", "Bc")][is.na(mdf[, c("Aa", "Ab", "Ac")])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one using `data.table v1.9.5` - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
cols1 = names(df1)[2:4]
cols2 = names(df2)[2:4]

foo <- function(x, y) {
    nas = is.na(x)
    x[nas] = y[nas]
    x
}
setDT(df1)[df2, c(cols1, cols2) := c(Map(foo, mget(cols1), 
                   mget(cols2)), mget(cols2)), on = "ID"]

> df1
#          ID Aa Ab Ac no.match Ba Bb Bc
# 1: Person.A  0  0  0        0  0 NA  0
# 2: Person.B  1  1  1        1 NA  1  1
# 3: Person.C  2  2  2        2  2  2  2
# 4: Person.D  1  1  2        2  1  2  2
# 5: Person.E  1  1  1        1  1  1  1
# 6: Person.F  1  1  1        2 NA NA NA
```

- `setDT()` converts `df1` to a *data.table* by reference.
- `setDT(df1)[df2, on = "ID"]` performs a join. For each row of `df2`, we find the matching rows in `df1` and extract the columns corresponding to matching rows..
- On the matching rows, we *update* columns in `cols1` and *add* new columns in `cols2` *by reference* using the `:=` operator. For updating columns, we extract the columns specified in `cols1` and `cols2` and replace `NA`s with the function `foo()`. For adding columns, we simply pull the columns `cols2`, using `mget()`. We concatenate the two lists using `c()`.

If you're interested, have a look at the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and even more for the explanation.  Could I ask how I would change the function to insert the row sums of cols2 into the Nas of cols1? Thanks again!